# Images is not hiding in Outlook 2016?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive email HTML, where everything is working fine in browser but not working in outlook. The code snippet is added can anybody help me here?

In outlook: I just want the first section showing in normal windows but I don't know what is happening. The paragraph section is successfully hidden but image is not getting hide.

```css
.show-me{
 mso-hide: all;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: none;
 line-height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}
.show-me img{
 mso-hide: all;
 overflow: hidden;
 max-height: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: none !important;
 line-height: 0;
 visibility: hidden !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {

.show-me{
 overflow:visible ;
  max-height:auto;
   width: 100%;
    display: table;
    line-height: 0;
 visibility: visible;
}
.show-me img{
 display : block ;
  width: 100%;
   height: auto ;
  border: 0 ;
}
.outer-table-desktop-only{
 display: none; 
 font-size: 0; 
 max-height: 0; 
 line-height: 0;
 mso-hide:all;
}
```

```html
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
      <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="outer-table-desktop-only">
   <tr>
     <td valign="top" height="300" background="http://msgfocus.com/files/amf_sage/workspace_42/MISC_New/600-600x300.jpg" style="height:300px; background-image:url('http://msgfocus.com/files/amf_sage/workspace_42/MISC_New/600-600x300.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;">
             <!--[if gte mso 9]>
               <v:image xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" id="theImage" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 300px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 1;" src="http://msgfocus.com/files/amf_sage/workspace_42/MISC_New/600-600x300.jpg" />               
        
                        
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 300px; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0; z-index: 2;">
                <v:fill opacity="0%" style="z-index: 1;"/> 
                <div>                       
                <![endif]--> 
             <!-- Containing Table -->
       <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
                     <td width="100%" height="300" align="center" valign="middle">
                         <!-- Contents -->
                         <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                 <tr>
    <td width="100%" valign="middle" style="font-size:32px; line-height:1.5em; color : #FFFFFF;"><p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:27px; line-height:1.5em; color:#ffffff;">This is a Email Title</p>
      <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:1.5em; color:#ffffff;">The Third Edition of Houser's best seller emphasizes the importance of being a good consumer of research and teaches readers how to conduct research in practice. Written in an engaging, conversational tone, the book uses concrete examples from professional literature to demonstrate how to effectively evaluate and interpret research articles—without relying on discipline-specific jargon.</p></td>
  </tr>
             </table>                       <!-- Contents END -->
                     </td>
               </tr>
             </table>
             <!-- Containing Table END-->
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>   
          </div></v:fill></v:rect><![endif]--> 
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<table class="show-me" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  <tr>        
     <td width="100%" valign="top" class="show-me" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="http://msgfocus.com/files/amf_sage/workspace_42/MISC_New/600-600x300.jpg" alt="Journal Cover" width="600" vspace="0" border="0"></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
    <td valign="top" class="show-me" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        
    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="show-me">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:27px; line-height:1em;color:#333333;"><p>This is a Email Title</p>
          <p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:1.5em; color:#333333;">The Third Edition of Houser's best seller emphasizes the importance of being a good consumer of research and teaches readers how to conduct research in practice. Written in an engaging, conversational tone, the book uses concrete examples from professional literature to demonstrate how to effectively evaluate and interpret research articles—without relying on discipline-specific jargon.</p></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]